# Disappearing HTML on first visit to the page with Gatsby and Material UI in production only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

I have a Gatsby blog with Material UI components fetching markdown files with GraphQL.

In development, everything works fine. In production (`gatsby build && gatsby serve`) however, the HTML is either not displayed or disappears very quickly after page loading when the page is the first page loaded only. If I navigate to another page, and back again, it loads correctly.

Interesting point, when I make the Typography component `variant="h6"` it works fine, but `variant="body1"` or no `variant` fails to load correctly. This makes me think it's something to do with the `<p>` tag.

My content is fetched from .md files with GraphQL and parsed through a Material-UI component with e.g. `<Typography align={props.align} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }} />`

This is the element from the inspector on first page load showing the empty DOM:

```
<div class="MuiGrid-root jss176 MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12 MuiGrid-grid-sm-6" style="background:#e0e0e0">
<p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body1 MuiTypography-alignJustify"></p>
</div>
```

Things I've tried:

1. Changing the `variant` of the Typography (as above)
2. Bypassing the template component and injecting the HTML straight into the page (no change)
3. Replacing the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with a string (no change)
4. Injecting the HTML straight into Typography without dangerouslySetInnerHTML (renders raw HTML fine)
5. Change browser (no change)
6. Clear cache, delete node_modules, `gatsby clean` rebuild, etc (no change)

Here one example of my template components:

```
function ImageBoxLeft(props) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Grid className={classes.root} container spacing={0}>
      {props.title && (
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Typography align="center" className={classes.title} component="h2" variant="h2">{props.title}</Typography>
        </Grid>
      )}
      <Grid component={Img} fluid={props.image} className={classes.image} item xs={12} sm={6} />
      <Grid className={classes.text} style={{ background: props.scheme2 ? theme.palette.scheme2.card : theme.palette.scheme1.card  }} item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <Typography align={props.align} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

And here is an example of the site page:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";
import { ImageBoxLeft } from 'components/ImageBox'
import CardSection from 'components/CardSection'
import EmailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MailOutline';

const buttons = [
  {
    text: 'Enquire about managing risk for your team',
    to: '/contact',
    icon: <EmailIcon />
  },
]

function About() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
        query {
          image1: file(relativePath: { eq: "img/general/home_main.jpg" }) {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(maxWidth: 900, maxHeight: 570) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
              }
            }
          }
          about: markdownRemark(frontmatter: { name: { eq: "about" } }) {
            html
            frontmatter {
              title
            }
          }
        }
      `}
        render={data => (
          <Fragment>
            <CardSection
              title="About Us"
              buttons={buttons}
              scheme2
            >
              <ImageBoxLeft
                align="justify"
                image={data.image1.childImageSharp.fluid}
                body={data.about.html}
                scheme2
              />
            </CardSection>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      />
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default About
```

And my packages:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.9.0",
    "gatsby": "^2.19.14",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.2.34",
    "gatsby-plugin-canonical-urls": "^2.1.13",
    "gatsby-plugin-feed": "^2.3.19",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.1.23",
    "gatsby-plugin-html-attributes": "^1.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-material-ui": "^2.1.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-preconnect": "^1.0.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.22",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.2.32",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.2.19",
    "gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader": "^1.0.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^1.0.5",
    "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files": "^2.1.28",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^3.1.34",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.39",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.6.38",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.3.6",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-twitter-embed": "^3.0.3"
  }
```

Comment: It seems my problem is related to this one: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5479 - something to do with Marked and wrapping <p> with another <p> causing a nested <p> issue

Comment: Have you tried using another component in Typography? Example `<Typography align={props.align} component="div" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }} />`

Comment: Thanks @LucasAraujo this lead to the answer below

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 8):

So the solution is to make the Typography component a `<div>` to avoid nested `<p>` tags which came from Lucas Araujo's comment above, and also adding a key as per this https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/717ee6eede217189820af2a644706a257e0a9623/packages/gatsby/cache-dir/default-html.js#L19

And this https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2750#issuecomment-341765585

And this https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5479

So my new working component looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
  Box,
  Typography
} from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(0),
    margin: theme.spacing(0)
  }
}));

function ArticleBody(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Box className={classes.root}>
      <Typography
        key={props.key}
        color={props.color ? props.color : "default"}
        align={props.align ? props.align : 'justify'}
        variant={props.variant ? props.variant : 'body1'}
        component="div"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.content }}
      />
    </Box>
  )
}

export default ArticleBody
```

Thanks for your help Lucas Araujo!